# Problems with Trigonometric Identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We just started this today in class and I have several homework problems, but I don't understand it at all. Can anyone show me step by step how to do this. The problem is $4/(\tan x + \cot x)$.

My teacher went ahead and told us the answer would be $4\sin x\cos x$, so we can make sure we use the right steps and get the correct answer. I am so lost in this. Please help me understand.

Comment: Please elaborate on what to do this this expression. What are the instructions?

Comment: My teacher just said to show the steps using the trig identities to get to the answer.I guess it is considered solving it? Not sure. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your teacher wants the expression simplified:

4/(tanx+cotx)

4/((sin/cosx)+(cosx/sinx))

4/((sin^2x/sinxcosx)+(cos^2x/sinxcosx))

4/((sin^2x+cos^2x)/(sinxcosx))

//sin^2x+cos^2x=1

=> 4/(1/(sinxcosx))

4sinxcosx

Comment: The King orders Ila Isabelle to choose his answer by clicking the check mark. And the King says your welcome.

Comment: Lol, as you command King.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition:
$$
\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x},\quad \cot x=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}.
$$
So
$$
\frac{4}{\tan x+\cot x}=\frac{4}{\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}+\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}}=
\frac{4}{\dfrac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2x}{\sin x\cos x}}
$$
Now, what can you do?

Comment: sin^2x + cos^2x= 1, so then I multiply 4*sinx*cosx. Please tell me I am right?

Comment: @IlaIsabelle Yes, you are.